# Neo4J calculating "connectedness" to a node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to put together a query that works out the "connectedness" between two given nodes (the blue and red nodes in the examples below).

The connectedness of a blue node is 1.0 if it's directly connected to red, or 0.0 if it has no connection to red (directly or transitively).

The algorithm is recursive. For a given sub-tree, "connectedness" is calculated from the average "connectedness" value of its directly connected nodes.

Your help would be much appreciated. Also, if you can spot an obvious flaw in the algorithm itself, I'm open to suggestions.

[image: Examples]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your start/end nodes have the label `Foo` (and `id` values `1` and `2`, respectively), and your relationships are of type `BAR`, the following will find the "connectedness" of all paths between them:

```
MATCH p=(:Foo {id:1})-[:BAR*]->(:Foo {id:2})
RETURN
  REDUCE(s = 1.0, n IN NODES(p)[0..-1] | s / SIZE((n)-->())) AS connectedness,
  p
```

Comment: Thanks so much @cybersam - your solution is very helpful, and has introduced me to some new Cypher syntax which will prove useful in other queries too